# SSIS For Loop - Wait for file to carry on

Tags: for-loop, ssis

I am creating an SSIS package that imports 10 different CSV files, however the availability of each file varies - so i want to get the file check to loop until all files are there and then start to import process.

I check this through a T-SQL script

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tblFileCheck') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE tbFileCheck;

CREATE TABLE tblFileCheck (
       id int IDENTITY(1,1)
      ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
      ,depth int
      ,isfile bit);

INSERT tblFileCheck 
EXEC xp_dirtree '\\reports\Reports\CSV', 10, 1

BEGIN
IF EXISTS (
SELECT COUNT(id)
     FROM tblFileCheck
     HAVING count(id) > 9
)
BEGIN
PRINT 'Success - Import Latest File'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
  RAISERROR ('Looping back to start - insufficient files to run', 16, 1 );  
END
END
```

However I cant get the loop to work, I have created a variable `varWaitForData` (int32, val = 0), created a SQL task editor with `result set = single row` and set the result set option to the parameter.
Set the `InitExpression @varWaitForData = 0` AND `EvalExpression @varWaitForData == 0`.

But i keep getting the error `[Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "varWaitForData": "Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0015005".`

Comment: When you run the query of your Execute SQL Task, what is its result?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different approach:

set up a variable called fileCount as int

script task: Get file count

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("\\reports\Reports\CSV");
Dts.Variables["User::fileCount"].Value = dir.GetFiles().Length;
```

Now set up a foreach file enumerator
and put a constraint on the path that fileCount > 9

Comment: Actually you can't use foreach if the csv files are different. you could use a container though holding each of the dataflows to get parallel execution.